# Wheel Shaped Scroll view For Moving Video Slowly

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, ios6, avplayer

can anyone tell me how to create a wheel shaped scrollview for moving the video as frame by frame slowly like in Coach Eye app and uber sense application..Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create UIScrollView like UINavigationBar size. Get Video assert split frame/sec using AVAssetImageGenerator insert ScrollView, get scroll view current content player time set avplayer current time.

Comment: Thanks yar..u really save my time.